# How to format the display of webform_select_options_info to include an image?

Tags: views, webforms, flags

Looking for some guidance on how to approach the formatting of the results of webform_select_options_info. What I want to present to the users is a dynamically populated list of items they flagged along with a checkbox. What I'd like to do is show a thumbnail of the image, the node title and a checkbox in  my list.

The function as I have it now is as follows

```
 function webform_hook_user_flag_sample_requests() {
   $view = views_get_view('webform_flag_views', TRUE);
   $view->set_display('webform_options');
   $view->execute();
   $options = array();
   if ($view->result) {
     $row_class = $view->style_options['row_class'];
     $attributes = $row_class ? " class='$row_class'" : '';
     foreach($view->result as $item) {
    $options[$item->product_id]= $item->commerce_product_title;
      }
       }
   else {
     $options[0] = t("Nothing");
   }
return $options;
      }
```

I'm not sure how to change the foreach loop to include additional fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still didn't get a good answer on modifying the syntax here but here is working result. I have a check box, thumb, and title all showing as a list in webform. Still not completely functional as the function doesn't seem to work for anonymous users, although the Flag is anonymous and I'm using sessions.

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Implements hook_webform_select_options_info().
     */
     function webform_hook_webform_select_options_info() {
       $items = array();
       if (function_exists('webform_hook_user_flag_sample_requests')) {
         $items['webform_hook_user_flag_sample_requests'] = array(
          'title' => t("Sample Requests (User Flag list)"),
          'options callback' => 'webform_hook_user_flag_sample_requests',
         );
       }

       return $items;
     }

     function webform_hook_user_flag_sample_requests() {
       $view = views_get_view('webform_flag_views', TRUE);
       $view->set_display('webform_options');
       $view->execute();
    // dpm($view);
       $options = array();

       if ($view->result) {
     //    $row_class = $view->style_options['row_class'];
     //    $attributes = $row_class ? " class='$row_class'" : '';
         foreach($view->result as $item) {
        $options[$item->product_id]= $item->commerce_product_title . render($item->field_field_image[0]['rendered']);
          }
           }
       else {
         $options[0] = t("Nothing");
       }
    return $options;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Drupal's FAPI won't allow markup in the labels of checkboxes. It gets sent through check_plain which escapes your html.

What you could try instead is writing a [custom render function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#post_render) for that form element.

Comment: Well the tutorial I referenced appears to have a select list with checkboxes, so it must be possible